# Determine height of a binary search tree C++

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

What is the best way to create a method that determines the height of a Binary Search Tree class? For instance: bst.height() would return 1 if it contains only 1 item; return 2 if it contains 3 items and is balanced, or return 3 otherwise; return 3 if it contains 4 items and is balanced, or return 4 otherwise. This may be a somewhat different implementation than usual.

Comment: You can think of height of a node being max(leftSubtree,rightSubtree)+1. Using this, you can work your way up to root level

Comment: Possible duplicate of "The best way to calculate the height of a binary search tree": http://stackoverflow.com/q/575772/716443

Comment: @DavidO Yes, but I'm not referring to a self-balancing tree.

Comment: If the tree isn't self-balancing, and you input fully sorted data one element at a time, you will end up with a tree that has one long leg, and one missing leg; practically a flat linked list.  That means your worst case for "walking the tree" will be O(n).  It's probably best, in such a situation, to keep track upon insert, delete, and rebalance.  That would give you an O(1) answer every time, at the small overhead of keeping track on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way would be to update the height while you insert and delete.